# Calling Postgresql stored procedures in Mulesoft 3.8

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, mule, anypoint-studio

I can't call PostgreSQL stored procedures by using `<db:stored-procedure> . .  . </db:stored-procedure>`. The problem is we have to use 'Call' keyword if we choose `<db:stored-procedure>` and it only works in certain database such as MySQL. In PostgreSQL, we have to use 'Select' keyword to call a function/Stored Procedure, 'Call' returns the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it's the perfect solution but I found a workaround. Just choose `<db:select> . . . </db:select>` to call a store procedure/functions.